# States для конопок

Tags: python, aiogram

Как добавить State для не инлайновой кнопки на aiogram?

Answer (score 0):

### Никак

[Клавиатурная кнопка Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) представляет текст, который отправляется боту при нажатии. Далее вы на уровне приложения принимаете этот текст и работаете с ним. Состояние вы можете задать пользователю на уровне своего приложения.

Более того, у фреймворка `aiogram` есть встроенная машина состояний. Вот [пример её использования](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py).